# Installing IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0 on Eclipse 4.4.2 (LUNA) failed with following errors

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
Operating system is RHEL 6

The first time, it last for a hour then said failed, the subsequent tries failed right of start.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.branding,1.4.0.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.core,1.4.0.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui,1.4.0.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility,2.3.0.v201311210251
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user,3.2.100.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.annotate,1.0.100.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.branding,3.4.0.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core,3.4.0.v201401221940
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db,2.2.100.v201311210251
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.ui,2.1.100.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen,2.3.100.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui,3.4.0.v201312050012
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.http.core,1.0.300.v20130918_1641
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.http.ui,1.0.400.v20130918_1641
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.preview,1.1.300.v20130918_1641
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.adapter,1.1.300.v20130918_1641
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.transaction,1.8.0.201405281451
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.validation,1.8.0.201405281429
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.workspace,1.5.1.201405281451
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.common.core,1.7.0.201408201453
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.clipboard.core,1.7.0.201408201453
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.commands.core,1.7.0.201408201453
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.core,1.7.0.201408201453
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core,1.7.0.201408201453
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.common.feature,1.4.0.v201405081709-67E-AkF7BJB8CKDFRZ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature,3.4.0.v201405081709-7V7dEpFC7sReAYthMgWBL39c7
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql,2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature,3.2.400.v20140501_1027-7L3FJPCcNBHRBuJmLBVNB
```

Comment: I would try again later, as it is complaining "no repository" found.

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming from Eclipse complaining that it could not find any repositories. It looks like a network problem.

You can also try with this direct link: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_7.0.0.zip

Open Eclipse > Help > Install software... > Add button, select the archive and continue with the installation.